# Transitioning an element from fixed to static positioning makes page jump to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Look at the [following example](https://skyflame00.github.io/test/). We have a green block. When in portrait orientation, it should be fixed at the top of the screen. When in landscape orientation, it should be static. There are media queries that control this behavior.

Scroll the page down to some distance (no matter how long it is), then in devtools change the orientation to landscape and you'll notice that the screen jumps to the top of the page. What causes this to happen?

If you try to manually change CSS classes to make the block static (I mean not on orientation change), it won't jump to the top. So there is a button on the page for manual removing, try it out.

I also found that if you change the width of this green block to, for instance, 10% or give it "bottom: 0" it won't cause the screen to jump.

It reproduces in Chrome (macOS and Android, not reproducing on iOS)

Sample code from the link above:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const page = document.querySelector('.page');
    const action = document.querySelector('.action');

    action.onclick = () => {
        page.classList.toggle('page_pinned');
    };
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 5000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
}

.sticky {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.sticky {
  background: green;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.action {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .page_pinned .sticky {
    position: fixed;
  }
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .page_pinned .sticky {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page page_pinned">
            <div class="sticky"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="action">Click me to toggle fixed/static positioning</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this question is very attractive. for a solution, we can use JavaScript orientation detection and then add a new class for the landscape orientation and change the position. but why the scroll jump to the top and why it doesn't happen in the code snippet that I edited? you can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I was weird for me, I simplify your question and test it on and on put all results were the same as your result. Until I saw this sentence:

> It reproduces in Chrome (macOS and Android, not reproducing on iOS)

I tested your [given link](https://skyflame00.github.io/test/) on the **Firefox** and **Safari** on macOS Catalina and your codes have no issue and work well.

- Firefox, Responsive Design Mode (Galaxy S9) on macOS:

  This screenshot captured after changing orientation from portrait to landscape and it didn't affect on the scroll

  [image]
- Safari, Responsive Design Mode (iPhone 8 Plus):

  As you see changing orientation didn't affect scroll too.

  [image]
- Google Chrome, Toggle Device Toolbar (Galaxy S5) on macOS:

  Just like you said, on Google Chrome after changing orientation from *portrait* to *landscape* the scroll jumped to the top. definitely, it is a ***BUG*** of Google Chrome, because it doesn't' happen from *landscpae* to *portrait*, and it just happens from *portrait* to *landscape* when a child node will be changed its *position*. for other cases, it works without issue.

  [image]

## Solution

For such these cases I decide to change the solution and the new solution should cover the bug on Google Chrome and works properly the same as before on other browsers, I omit your media queries, use `static` instead of `absolute` for removing sticky situation and add two CSS classes for the orientation situations and a tiny JavaScript code for handling the interaction:

```js
var addClass = function () {
    var ori = screen.orientation.type;
    var bodyClassList = document.body.classList;

    if (ori === 'portrait-primary') {
        bodyClassList.add('portrait');
        bodyClassList.remove('landscape');
    } else {
        bodyClassList.remove('portrait');
        bodyClassList.add('landscape');
    }
};

addClass();
screen.orientation.onchange = addClass;
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 5000px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
}

.sticky {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

body.portrait .sticky {
    position: fixed;
}

body.landscape .sticky {
    position: static;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ori</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Hint**: we should report this bug.